# how to show that $\int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)dz=\int_Tf(z)dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

$\omega$ is an open subset of complex numbers and let $T\subset\omega$ be a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\omega$. f is a function holomorphic in $\omega$ except possibly at a point a inside T. Then let $C_\epsilon$ be a circle centered at the point b with radius $\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon$ small enough so that the circle lies inside the interior of T. I am just wondering how to show that $\int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)dz=\int_Tf(z)dz$?

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Theorem should facilitate.

Comment: Do you mean $b$ to be the same as $a$?  Use Cauchy's theorem for the region inside $T$ and outside $C_\epsilon$.

Comment: How to apply Cauchy's theorem to it? since one is a triangle and one is a circle.

Comment: take one point $a$ on $T$ and an other $b$ on $C_\epsilon$. Define the contour $\gamma = a \underset{T^+}{\to} a \cup a \to b \cup b \underset{C_\epsilon^-}{\to} b \cup b \to a$ (where $+$ and $-$ means following the counter counter-clock and clockwise direction). It is a closed contour, $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the interior, hence $0 = \int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_T f(z) dz+\int_a^b-\int_{C^\epsilon} f(z) dz+\int_b^a f(z) dz = \int_T f(z) dz-\int_{C^\epsilon} f(z) dz$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!